# Can snow dunes form naturally?

Tags: science-based, deserts, ice, landscaping

Suppose I have a very big area as big as Gobi desert and it is windy all years round, but it is covered in snow instead of sand since Earth is experiencing another ice age right now. I am not sure if dunes would still forms regardless of the type of particles or it must be sand and only certain sand?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Snow dunes already form on Earth, like one can see in all regions where snow and wind are plenty.

[image]

However they do not reach the sheer dimension of sand dunes because of the difference in the interaction between the constituting particles.

While sand grain keep staying separate and individual under the conditions present in a sand dune (to start coalescence they need to be at pressures and temperature way higher then those present on the surface), snow flakes can very quickly and easily coalesce and form larger bodies of something which will end up being a block of ice.

What you end up having is then not a dune but an ice sheet/bulge.

To have dunes you need to have particles which do not coalesce together.

Comment: Is this merely a function of the temperature? Would lower (or possibly higher) temperatures prevent the formation of ice blocks and cause the dunes to remain?

Comment: @JohnO, it is not just temperature, but also pressure. Sand is composed of silica and other minerals. It resists pressure much more than ice crystals. It takes less pressure to squish snow flakes into a cohesive ice block than it takes to squish silica particles into a larger rock. This limits the size of "snow dunes".

Comment: We don't have temperatures low enough for prolonged periods. A single warmup is enough to glue some of the crystals.

Answer (score 17):

I've lived (and currently live) in areas where blowing snow is common. Of course dunes form, though we call them drifts, and they can form thicknesses of a dozen feet where other surfaces have but inches. From a practical perspective, there's little difference between solid water and solid silica beyond density. But understanding how dunes form is important. High enough winds will flatten everything. Low enough winds won't form dunes. The right winds form washboards (dunes).

But it's also important what the limitations of ice crystals are. Photons are hot! Even in the coldest regions of Earth, sunlight will melt surface ice. This means you must have a low enough level of solar energy that the surfaces of the dunes aren't subjected to a daily thaw-freeze cycle.

Of course, as I think about it, that thaw-freeze cycle might be a wonderful suspension-of-disbelief reason why snow dunes form in a way that looks exactly like desert dunes. Should sunlight thaw the lighter density snow during the low-wind day, the high-wind night can refreeze it and pile it up, causing a natural form of windbreak, which would be the core of dunes. The leeward side of the dune would always be icy compared to the fluffy windward side. This would also cause a really cool story element.

Comment: My experience is that snow drifts stay dune-like mobile only as long as it is very cold and windy. The first thaw-freeze cycle will solidify them into immobile hillocks. Drifty snow is made of small solid pieces of frozen water; and such tiny pieces of ice really really want to weld together, and will do so at the slightest opportunity.

Comment: @AlexP We get snow drifts throughout the winter despite the thaw-freeze cycle, which suggests that the depth of the cycle is critical - but your point is entirely valid, thus the reason why I suggested the solution on the basis of suspension-of-disbelief.

Comment: I think you have leeward and windward backwards here. The windward side is the side facing the wind that will be scoured. The leeward side is where the snow will accumulate.

Comment: If it continues to snow, the character of drifts will continue to change, even if the core of the younger ones has become immobile. You may end up with layers and various levels of crunchy crust in the midst of more uniform compacted snow, which represent days of sunlight (and a thaw-freeze cycle). Alternatively, if it's cloudy enough to keep snowing, you may not get enough sun to have a thaw-freeze cycle.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor, no... I'm using the words the way I intended. The wind would reduce ice to particulates again. The leeward side would remain icy. I am assuming that we only have solar heating in a subfreezing environment, which is very thin and easily returned to particulate form by wind. It's the side that doesn't get the wind where the thaw-freeze cycle builds due to particulate settling that I expect would build up. Could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 7):

Have snow *on* the sand dunes!
[image: image of sand dunes covered in snow]
Just need an area meeting the conditions for a desert, and have it close enough to a region where snow can occurr. Regular weather patterns move snow into the desert, and viola, snowy dunes. [:

As for dunes made exclusively of snow, it's not to my understanding that snow works like that. Whereas sandy deserts are blown by the wind over time to form dunes, snow is constantly replenished. It sticks to things like trees and stones, while sand kind of sits on things. Very different properties! Can't make a snowman out of sand yk?

Comment: It takes water and special packing to get sand so that you can carve a sandman out of it. But it can be done - see all the sand carving contests.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, snow dune-like structures called [sastrugi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sastrugi) are a thing.

> Sastrugi are distinguished by upwind-facing points, resembling anvils, which move downwind as the surface erodes. These points usually lie along ridges perpendicular to the prevailing wind; they are steep on the windward side and sloping to the leeward side.

Answer (score 6):

"Not really", is the answer to that. The problem is that unlike sand, ice crystals can sinter together to form a larger solid blob, they can melt (with the water generally being absorbed into the surrounding snow) and they can also sublime (turning directly into water vapor... something that can happen with very find windblown particles). Snow flakes rapidly break up into smaller ice crystals when windblown, unlike sand grains that take much longer to wear down.

You can get some transitional forms that seem a bit like dunes in the form of snowdrifts, but these are temporary things and continued wind can transform them into much harder, pointer and more angular structures (the sastrugi mentioned by Monty Wild) in contrast to the generally softer and more rounded structure that sand forms as sand grains can't sinter together or sublime away under normal circumstances. Wind-hammered snow can have almost rock-like hardness, and without a supply of fresh snow surface ice will be scoured away by the wind and sublime into the air causing features to reduce over time.

Combinations of wind and sun and dry air can cause some visually striking things such as penitentes:

[image: Penitentes ice formations at the southern end of the Chajnantor plain in Chile]

These spikes of snow form in very dry, cold mountainous areas and can reach several metres tall.

([image credit ESO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Penitentes_Ice_Formations.png))

> Suppose I have a very big area as big as Gobi desert and it is windy all years round, but it is covered in snow instead of sand

What you're more likely to have is something like an [ice sheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_sheet) where any interesting shapes are going to be driven by glacier flow more than by wind effects. Glaciated terrain can certainly be interesting and varied, but it only superficially resembles a sandy desert.

Also have a think about where the moisture is coming from to drive your snowfall, and what is triggering the precipitation... if you want heavy snowfall over long timescales, you're probably going to want some mountains, rather than a big plain.